# How to print results intermittently when applying a function to a large data set in R?

Tags: r, function, web-scraping, rvest, purrr

I'm trying to scrape a few different details from a large number of URLs (35000). I've defined a few functions using the rvest workflow, and I'm using map to apply each function to each url, building a tibble directly from the functions. My issue is that because there are so many urls it takes a really long time to run the whole thing, and I can't figure out a way to save results as I go (unless I make it a loop, which I think is even slower).

The only way I could think to get around this is to map over chunks of the urls and fill the tibble accordingly. But this code is really inefficient, and requires me to manually enter a lot of numbers over and over.

```
library(rvest); library(tidyverse)

#define function to scrape webdata
##i actually have multiple functions for each css tag i want, and create a tibble column for each one

get_web_info <- function(url) {
  read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("h3:nth-of-type(1)") %>%
  html_text()
}

#create tibble scraping the first 500 urls 
##only scrape the first 500 because otherwise there's no output until all 35000 urls are done, which takes more than a day

scraped <- tibble(
  web_info = map(url_vector[1:500], possibly(get_web_info, otherwise = NULL)),
  original_url = url_vector[1:500]
)

#fill in the next 500 rows of the tibble by scraping the next 500 urls
##i would have to copy and paste the code below, manually changing which rows i'm filling in and mapping 

scraped$web_info[500:1000] <- map(url_vector[500:1000], possibly(get_web_info, otherwise = NULL))
```

The code above technically works, but I'm aware it's very inefficient and prone to error (especially as I actually have 4 functions and would be doing the above 4 times).

Saving results from a function mapping over a large dataset must be a common issue, but I just can't find anything for how this is tackled.

Comment: A wild ass guess would be that the bottleneck here is `rvest` (i.e., the http call) and not R / your function.

Comment: rvest is probably what's making it slow, you're right, but that's not necessarily an issue if I could save my results as it goes. I figured since the code above works on 500 urls, it should work for 35000 but I can't leave it running for 3 days with no output.

Comment: Yeah, but then what's the harm of saving? The intermittent saving will not slow down your process (relatively speaking). If you want it to run faster, you'll need to open up more connections.

Comment: By the way: you're scraping `url[500]` twice. :-)

Comment: There's been some discussion of adding progress bars to `map`, but I don't think it's implemented. This post shows a working example of adding it using the `progress` package: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/149#issuecomment-365270639

Comment: @Roman I very much want to save! But I just don't think this is a very elegant way of doing it, and is prone to error as I'm copy and pasting a lot (If I saved every 500 urls the same way as above, I would copy and paste 70 times...) I just can't seem to find a better way of doing it (and I'm not a very experienced programmer). 
And yes I am, thanks for catching that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's been some discussion of adding progress bars to map, but I don't think it's implemented. [On the issue thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/149#issuecomment-365270639), though, **jtrecenti** posted some code that uses the `progress` package to add a progress bar to `map`. The example below works, but I'm not sure it will work with your code:

```
progressively <- function(.f, .n, ...) {
  pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(total = .n, ...)
  function(...) {
    pb$tick()
    .f(...)
  }
}

input <- 1:5
fun <- function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(.2)
  sample(x)
}
progress_fun <- progressively(fun, length(input))
purrr::map(input, progress_fun)
```

This shows a progress bar as it runs, and then returns:

```
[[1]]                                                                                               
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 1 2

[[4]]
[1] 2 1 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 1 4 3 2
```